# Interpolation of Colors

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to interpolate between 2 colors and, given a specific number, generate an array with that number of interpolated colors.

I found that D3 has a method called `d3.interpolate()`, but I don't know how to use it.

How can I use D3 interpolator to generate an array of colours given the two colors to interpolate and the number of desired interpolated colors?

Comment: You had no **question** in your post, just a statement, almost a moaning. I edited it to a meaningful question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For using a D3 interpolator you just need to understand that the argument you'll pass to the interpolator varies from 0 to 1. The [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate) is clear:

> The returned function i is called an interpolator. Given a starting value a and an ending value b, it takes a parameter t in the domain [0, 1] and returns the corresponding interpolated value between a and b. An interpolator typically returns a value equivalent to a at t = 0 and a value equivalent to b at t = 1.

So, given this interpolator, going from `red` to `green`:

```
var colorInterpolator = d3.interpolateRgb("red", "green");
```

We just need to pass the values going from 0 to 1. For example, to create an array with 7 colors, we'll pass these values to the interpolator:

```
[0, 0.16, 0.33, 0.5, 0.66, 0.83, 1]
```

Check this demo:

```js
var colorInterpolator = d3.interpolateRgb("red", "green");

var steps = 7;

var colorArray = d3.range(0, (1 + 1 / steps), 1 / (steps - 1)).map(function(d) {
  return colorInterpolator(d)
});

console.log(colorArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Now, let's see the colors in that array:

```js
var colorInterpolator = d3.interpolateRgb("red", "green");

var steps = 7;

var colorArray = d3.range(0, (1 + 1 / steps), 1 / (steps - 1)).map(function(d) {
  return colorInterpolator(d)
});

d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(colorArray)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "myDivs")
  .style("background-color", String)
```

```css
.myDivs {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Something up with that snippet Gerardo. But nice solution

Comment: @ofey The snippet is working OK for me... don't you see the colors?

Comment: I don't know why but I see an error, https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17167992/29669300-db6f2926-88da-11e7-81f7-26aba0c052a7.png

Comment: That's a strange bug. You can clearly see, even in that image, that the reference is there.

Comment: It is odd, oh well. Maybe the code is fine if run elsewhere or locally.

Comment: Nope, the code is fine as it is and it's working here in the SO snippet. You have a bug in **your** end. A very strange one, by the way.

Comment: Perhaps it's only me, anyway just bringing it to your attention.

Comment: Even weirder than the error is that now it works fine. Lucky I got a screen shot of it when it occurred.

Comment: Probably what happened is that D3 source site was down for you at the moment you clicked the snippet.

Comment: I have tried other functions such as d3.interpolateHsl & d3.interpolateLAB but seems like they return same result. I want to use other methods to generate different interpolated colors.

Comment: var color1 = 'white',
 color2 = 'black'; 

var steps = 20;

var colorInterpolator = d3.interpolateRgb(color1, color2);

var colorArray = d3.range(0, (1 + 1 / steps), 1 / (steps - 1)).map(function(d) {
  return colorInterpolator(d)
});
console.log(colorArray)

colorInterpolator = d3.interpolateHsl(color1, color2);

colorArray = d3.range(0, (1 + 1 / steps), 1 / (steps - 1)).map(function(d) {
  return colorInterpolator(d)
});
console.log(colorArray)

They both return same array is it normal ?!

Comment: Here, at stack overflow, it's good manners accepting a useful answer. Besides that, as this is another issue, please post *another* question.

Comment: yes I'm accepting it but we are discussing here in comment no ?!

Comment: No, that's what I tried to explain above: If you have another issue, please post another question. If you ask this, here, in the comments I am the only one reading it, but if you ask it as another question everybody's gonna read it. And, again, this is a *different* issue: you asked how to interpolate colors, and I explained it. Now you're asking why `d3.interpolateRgb` and `d3.interpolateHsl` are returning the same result.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I opened another tread if you have the kindness to answer it I'll be gratful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885426/d3-interpolate-returns-weired-results

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [d3-color](https://github.com/d3/d3-color) to see how colors are manipulated and interpolated within d3

Comment: Yes I checked but I didn't find how to genertate an Array of interpolated colors, given 2 colors and number of wanted colors.